# List<string> how to get a specific string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list

Im having a List, and the count of the list i 4. Now i want to get a specific string, and remove it from the list. I've tried with some code, and i thought that was enough, but my mistake. I think i'm close.! "navn" is a name which are achieved from a textbox. "strings" are my List strings..

```
if (strings.Contains(navn, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  Console.WriteLine("going inside");
  strings.Remove(navn);
  listBox_varer.Items.Clear();
  string pr = "";
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= (strings.Count - 1); i++)
   {
      pr = strings[i] + "\n";
      listBox_varer.Items.Add(pr);
    }
  }
  else
  {
   Console.WriteLine("going in else");
   }
```

Comment: Then what isn't working?

Comment: the output writes "going in else", when i'm certain of having a string which are in the list.. :)

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: if you are sure strings contain navn, can you try without StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase?

Comment: it means your strings don't contain navn, pay more attention to the spaces

Comment: Please execute the following code before the if and give the result to us: `Console.WriteLine(strings.Aggregate (string.Empty, (s1, s2) => s1+"'"+s2+"', "));
Console.WriteLine("'"+navn+"'");`. This will stop the guessing. Please make sure you have `using System.Linq;` in your CS file.

Comment: @Anders - You may be certain, but you are wrong anyway. If the string `navn` is inside the list `strings`, then it wont go to the else block. Maybe a whitespace before or after either the list entry, or the `navn` variable? Set a break point on the `if` line, and inspect both the contents of `strings` and `navn` and you will probably spot the difference between them.

Comment: What is listBox_varer? is this a console app or a forms app?

Comment: Daniel<<<<
'Aeble
', 'Banan
', 'Broccoli
', 'Peberfrugt
',

Comment: and the second line? But I guess I can already see the problem: There is a space after each one of this entries, do you see that?

Comment: @AndersJensen: If you want people to be notified, use `@Username` and not `Username<<<<`!

Comment: Daniel << yes I can, but 2 secs..

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Sorry i'm new to this site. So didn't know the "@".. 
But i cant find the place where i'm putting the whitespace behind every name. And if i'm trying to put a whitespace behind "navn", and the searches after it in "strings", i'll still get the "going in else".

Comment: @AndersJensen Before adding an item to the lsit, trim it

Comment: @AndersJensen: Because you are new, I am telling you the things you need to know :-) I have to admit, this bug hunt is getting tiresome. Please provide a *short* but *complete* example with which we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: You want me to tell what I want to do?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I dont think that there is any whitespaces behind "navn". I've written: Console.WriteLine("What is navn? "+navn+"hey");

And the result are: What is navn? Bananhey

Comment: That's the problem. The entries in your list *have* a whitespace at the end.

Comment: All the strings in my list are from my database, and in my DB, thay dont have any whitespaces behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compares with ignore case, but the remove method doesn't. I would do something like this:

```
string match = strings.FirstOrDefault(c => String.Equals(c, navn, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
if (match != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("going inside");
   strings.Remove(match);
   listBox_varer.Items.Clear();
   for (int i = 0; i <= (strings.Count - 1); i++)
   {
       string pr = string.Concat(strings[i], Environment.NewLine);
       listBox_varer.Items.Add(pr);
    }
 }
 else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("going in else");
 }
```

Comment: @AndersJensen Then you haven't provided enough code. The error is somewhere else then

Comment: it can't be, because i have written some console writelines, and my output shows that everything is okay. So I don't know .(

Comment: @AndersJensen Stop the guessing and listen to us. I just tried this code, works fine

Comment: Prefer to use `String.Equals(a,b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` always... It is also safer with regard to nullvalues

Comment: You getting this answer correct because I fixed the bug with the trim method you suggested. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have found the item ignoring the case `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. So you have found `"foo"` ignoring the case in `("Foo", "Bar")` and you're trying to remove `"foo"` which is not in the list.

Try not to ignore the case or use LINQ

```
strings.RemoveAll(s => 
  String.Equals(s, navn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: That is some bad advice. `String.Equals(a,b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` would be just fine

Comment: @sehe I agree. This also makes it impossible to use the if / else structure he uses now

Comment: I agree too. I have modified the code - converting 2 string to lower case and compare them is an unnecessary overhead. I hope `String.Equals` is implement in a smart way:] A beginner`s mistake:(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your problem is to have the listbox reflecting your changing to the list, I have a short solution for you:

```
        ObservableCollection<string> strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        listBox.DataSource = strings;
        strings.Remove(navn);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `strings.Remove`  `Remove` function not compare by `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

```
for(i=0;i<strings.Count-1;i++){
   if(strings[i].Equals(navn,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
      strings.RemoveAt(i);
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is, that you cannot ensure that the value to be remved is entered in the right case, then this will help you:

```
        var entryToRemove = strings.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == navn.ToUpper());
        if (entryToRemove != null)
        {
            strings.Remove(entryToRemove);
        }
```